# Python Pandas: .apply taking forever?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a DataFrame 'clicks' created by parsing CSV of size 1.4G. I'm trying to create a new column 'bought' using apply function.

```
clicks['bought'] = clicks['session'].apply(getBoughtItemIDs)
```

In getBoughtItemIDs, I'm checking if 'buys' dataframe has values I want, and if so, return a string concatenating them. The first line in getBoughtItemIDs is taking forever. What are the ways to make it faster?

```
def getBoughtItemIDs(val):
  boughtSessions = buys[buys['session'] == val].values
  output = ''
  for row in boughtSessions:
    output += str(row[1]) + ","
  return output
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things that make this code run slowly.

- `apply` is essentially just syntactic sugar for a `for` loop over the rows of a column. There's also an explicit `for` loop over a NumPy array in your function (the `for row in boughtSessions` part). Looping in this (non-vectorised) way is best avoided whenever possible as it impacts performance heavily.
- `buys[buys['session'] == val].values` is looking up `val` across an entire column for each row of `clicks`, *then* returning a sub-DataFrame *and then* creating a new NumPy array. Repeatedly looking for values in this way is expensive (`O(n)` complexity each lookup). Creating new arrays is going to be expensive since memory has to be allocated and the data copied across each time.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you could try the following approach to get your new column.

First use `groupby` to group the rows of `buys` by the values in 'session'. `apply` is used to join up the strings for each value:

```
boughtSessions = buys.groupby('session')[col_to_join].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

where `col_to_join` is the column from `buys` which contains the values you want to join together into a string.

`groupby` means that only one pass through the DataFrame is needed and is pretty well-optimised in Pandas. The use of `apply` to join the strings is unavoidable here, but only one pass through the grouped values is needed.

`boughtSessions` is now a Series of strings indexed by the unique values in the 'session' column. This is useful because lookups to Pandas indexes are `O(1)` in complexity.

To match each string in `boughtSessions` to the approach value in `clicks['session']` you can use `map`. Unlike `apply`, `map` is fully vectorised and should be very fast:

```
clicks['bought'] = clicks['session'].map(boughtSessions)
```